# Toolbar, BottomNavigationView and FrameLayout in one XML layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

I need help in my XML layout, since I need to put Toolbar, FrameLayout, BottomNavigationView in one activity, Below is my code, the problem that the toolbar not appeared only the  FrameLayout and BottomNavigationView

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_layout" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar"
        />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/horizontalDivider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.3dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />


    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        layout="@layout/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try adding bottom constraint to include for appbar to parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/aa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontalDivider"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/horizontalDivider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_content" />


    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        layout="@layout/aa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontalDivider" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]